# ColdFusion - DateTime Format with GMT offset

Tags: datetime, coldfusion, coldfusion-10, datetimeoffset

I am using ColdFusion 10 to make some REST calls and the date returned is using a GMT offset.

Example: `2013-03-25T14:30:40-04:00`

I need this formatted for 2 purposes:

1. Screen Display so it looks something like `mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss`
2. To Insert into mySQL.

I have tried a variety of the CF time/date functions but continue to get the "is not a valid date format"

I thought maybe the `#ParseDateTime(i.submitted_at,"pop")#` would handle it with POP but same issue.

Spent a few hours now trying multiple variations and googling around now just going in circles.  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the UDF `DateConvertISO8601()` on CFLib.

[DateConvertISO8601(ISO8601dateString, targetZoneOffset) on CFLib](http://www.cflib.org/udf/DateConvertISO8601)

> **Description:**
>   This function take a string that holds a date in ISO 8601 and converts it to ODBC datetime, but could be adapted to convert to whatever you like. It also will convert to a datetime in a timezone of your choice by specifying the offset, i.e. it could take a datetime in GMT and convert to PT. See http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime for description of ISO 8601, the International Standard for the representation of dates and times.
>
> **Return Values:**
>   Returns a datetime.

The source code is viewable at the link I provided.

Answer (score 3):

This, 2013-03-25T14:30:40-04:00, is a string.  If you run this:

```
x = left(2013-03-25T14:30:40-04:00, 19);
```

you get 2013-03-25T14:30:40.  You can use the replace function to replace the T with a space.  You can then to this

```
DateTimeVar =parsedatetime('2013-03-25 14:30:40');
```

Now you have a datetime variable that you can format.  If necessary you can do a datediff with the offset from GMT.

Answer (score 3):

This is an informational answer, not a direct answer to the question.

ColdFusion 11 has updated the [ParseDateTime()](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-m-r/parsedatetime.html) function so that it will correctly convert the ISO-8601 date/time strings to a ColdFusion datetime object.

Answer (score 2):

With a number of remote requests and responses, the date / time values can often be returned in ISO format. In your case, the mask looks like this:

```
YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssTZD (eg 1997-07-16T19:20:30+01:00)
```

In this ISO format, the T string is a literal representation of a marker where the time stamp starts in the string (with the offset following directly).

Below is a reusable function that will convert an ISO date format into a useable ColdFusion date time object:

```
<cffunction name="ISOToDateTime" access="public" returntype="string" output="false" 
    hint="Converts an ISO 8601 date/time stamp with optional dashes to a ColdFusion   
        date/time stamp.">
    <cfargument name="Date" type="string" required="true" hint="ISO 8601 date/time stamp." />
        <cfreturn ARGUMENTS.Date.ReplaceFirst(
            "^.*?(\d{4})-?(\d{2})-?(\d{2})T([\d:]+).*$",
            "$1-$2-$3 $4"
            ) />
</cffunction>
```

You can then call the function like so to output or return a ColdFusion-friendly version of the date time:

```
ISOToDateTime( "2013-03-25T14:30:40-04:00" )
```

That function is courtesy of Ben Nadel. The original blog post can be found here:

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/811-Converting-ISO-Date-Time-To-ColdFusion-Date-Time.htm

You can also convert the date time value using the offset, if required. Again, Ben Nadel has a great blog post outlining how to accomplish this:

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1595-Converting-To-GMT-And-From-GMT-In-ColdFusion-For-Use-With-HTTP-Time-Stamps.htm

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, but while this appears to work it actually gives dirty data.  Consider two dates: "2014-08-19T11:02:20.633-07:00" and "2014-08-19T11:02:20.633-04:00".  These dates are actually 3 hours apart, but the above code shows both dates as the same value: "2014-08-19 11:02:20".  The following linked article talks about timezone conversions, but really only deals with the server's preferred timezone; not a timezone offset within a date string.

Answer (score 1):

CF10 can use this code as stated in the example of the [parseDateTime() doc](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-m-r/parsedatetime.html).

```
<cfset string = "1997-07-16T19:20:30+01:00">
<cfset date = parseDateTime(string, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX")>
```