# Making an API (Wordpress) Date usable with Coldfusion

Tags: mysql, wordpress, date, coldfusion

Scratching my head a bit with this one folks!

I'm using the Wordpress API to return posts & comments, which I then need to add to a local database (MySQL) using ColdFusion. I keep hitting a stumbling block with the dates returned though.

I'm using cfhttp with the API, then DeserializeJSON to work with the data returned.

An example date being returned is - `2013-06-25T17:20:24+01:00`

When I run `#CreateODBCDateTime(thedate)#` I get the following error;

> 2013-06-25T17:20:24+01:00 is an invalid date or time string.

I'm pretty sure I've worked with dates in this format the same way before, without any errors - so I can't see why this one is failing.

Here is valid code to reproduce the issue.

```
<cfset theDate = '2013-06-25T17:20:24+01:00'>
<cfdump var="#CreateODBCDateTime(theDate)#">
```

Comment: WTF? I wish there was a way to flag people as incompetent closers. This is not off-topic in any way at all; it's simply a [duplicate of this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15658756/coldfusion-datetime-format-with-gmt-offset).

Answer (score 3):

Well I didn't spot this when I searched before posting, but I saw it appear in the 'related' area - [ColdFusion - DateTime Format with GMT offset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15658756/coldfusion-datetime-format-with-gmt-offset)

The top solution, using the UDF has sorted the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the `parseDateTime` function

```
<cfset myDate = '2013-06-25T17:20:24+01:00'>
<cfset myDate = parseDateTime(myDate)>
<cfdump var="#myDate#">
```

This dumps out `{ts '2013-06-25 11:20:24'}`